# Global collection for use Web API v2

Tags: c#, global-variables, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to create a "Global" dictionary that could be used in my web api v2 project. I would like to collect the usernames of all clients that have authenticated with my API and the time they were authenticated.

Since each client would represent a different HTTP context how could I safely store this data so it can be accessed from other methods in the application? Ideally I would like to add the username and the time they authenticated within m CustomOAuthProvider class as this is where the user authentication occurs.

I would like to avoid using a database as the information is really small and I only need the data while the app is running.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Global.asax` define a prop `public static MyClass MyReference {get; set;}`. Then in your method where the user is authorized (logged in), modify this object: `Global.MyReference.UpdateMethod(currentUser)`.

Comment: What if I do not have a `Global.asax`? Instead I have a `Startup.cs` class.